# Fill context from REST API and use it in a React component with useEffect and useContext

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-hooks, react-context, use-effect

## Prerequisite

I have a form in a component with some inputs and these inputs need some configuration data. The configuration data come from REST API.

## Goal

Call the REST API and store the configuration data in React context so it will be reused.

## What is done

1/ I created component and its inputs.
2/ I used mock configuration data to render component.
3/ I created the context so I replaced mock configuration data with a new set of configuration data provided by the React context (always mock). 
4/ I Filled the context with configuration data from a REST API.

## Problem

I use context API in my component but the returned configuration data from context is empty.

```
interface ContextType {
  formConfig: any[];
}

export const Context = React.createContext<ContextType>({
 formConfig: [],
 getFormConfig: () => [],
});


export const ContextProvider: React.FC<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ children }) => {

  let formConfig: any[] = [];

  function getFormConfig() {
    return formConfig;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function fetchData() {
      formConfig = await ServiceConfig.getFormTypes();
      console.log(formConfig, 'use effect of context'); // It shows the conf
    })();
  }, []);


  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        getFormConfig,
        formConfig
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

const FormUI: React.FC = () => {


    const { getFormConfig } = useContext(Context);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(getFormConfig(), 'form'); // it is empty here
    }, []);

    return (
        <ContextProvider>
            ....
        </ContextProvider>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let formConfig: any[] = [];` is just an variable, when you rerender it, it will be created again and assign `[]` to it.

You need to store it in a state.

```
const [formConfig, setFormConfig] = React.useState([])
```

And in the async function, you set the state

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async function fetchData() {
      formConfig = await ServiceConfig.getFormTypes();
      setFormConfig(formConfig) // setting the state
      console.log(formConfig, 'use effect of context'); // It shows the conf
    })();
  }, []);
```

Sorry for not being able to give you the answer in typescript